# Какую локальную базу данных оптимальнее выбрать для простого проекта в Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, sql, база-данных, sqlite, linq

Здравствуйте. У меня есть проект. Это клиент сайта, которых хранит список просмотренных вами сериалов. 
Запрос своего списка с сайта занимает время, особенно, если список большой. Самое меньшее запрос тормозил работу программы 5(!) секунд. Без списка приложение не имеет смысла, а значит и не может начать работать.

В связи с этим я подумал решить проблемы следующим образом. Запрашивать список с сайта при первом запуске программы и авторизации в локальную БД. Далее выводить информацию с неё. Обновление БД осуществялось бы только данными с сервера посредством запроса списка в определённым интервалом или же при внесении изменений в список пользователем.

**Пример.** Пользователь впервые запустил программу. Программа запросила логин и пароль и запомнила пользователя. Затем отправила запрос на сервер и получила список. Первый запуск в любом случае будет долгим. Далее эти данные бы сохранялись в локальной БД. Пользователю уже отображался бы список из БД. Дабы поддерживать данные локальной БД актуальными, раз, например, в 5 минут, программа отправляла бы по новой запрос на сервер и обновляла данные. Или же при инициировании пользователем в софте изменений (добавлении просмотренных серий или прочего). Это бы уже делалось в отдельном потоке.

При последующих запусках программы, она бы запускалась мгновенно, отображая пользователю сохранённый локально список, при этом инициировала бы запрос на обновление в отдельном потоке.

**Требования к БД**

- Локальная. БД с списком сериалов должны храниться на компьютере пользователя в папке программы.
- Портативная. БД не должна требовать от пользователя установки дополнительных библиотек на компьютер пользователя, помимо разве что .Net Framework, который будет требовать сама программа. Разве что это будут портативные библиотеки, которые будут внутри папки самой программы.
- Не громоздкая. Так как БД будет на компьютере пользователя, то не хотелось, чтобы таблица в 10 полей при 1000 строках весила под гигабайт.
- Поддержка LINQ. Нативно или посредством подключением сторонних библиотек, хотелось бы выполнять все запросы через LINQ, а не SQLConnect.

Скорее всего, будет одна база данных и 4 таблицы в ней. Каких-либо сложных вещей вроде хранимых процедур или триггеров от неё не требуется. Только хранение. Все действия с ней буду делать непосредственно через программу.

Рассмативал как вариань sqlite, но не уверен, что в ней есть хорошая поддержка LINQ. И решил сначала посоветоваться. Если знаете хороший способ подружить sqlite с LINQ или же есть решение по лучше, то буду благодарен за помощь.

Comment: Тебе нужен нативный LINQ? Теоретически, LINQ можно присобачить к какой угодно базе самому. Описываешь сущности в виде классов и методы обновления. И кстати, ты можешь грузить данные в DataTable и над ними выполнять любые LINQ операции.

Comment: @iluxa1810 мне надо, чтобы база данных существовала и после выхода из приложение и сохраняла все данные, а не только пока запущено..

Comment: Есть же SQLite, хорош всем

Comment: @PrimusSingularis а есть годный гайд/библиотеки, как его в купе с linq использовать?

Comment: @Mr.Modest какой именно Linq вам нужен IEnumerable или IQueryable?

Comment: @PrimusSingularis чтобы с таблицами можно было работать, как с обычными коллекциями в C#, полагаю.. К примеру, `titles.Where(x => x.episodCount > 10).OrderBy(x => x.name)`

Comment: @Mr.Modest я использую в связке с Dapper, но sql вам надо будет самому писать

Comment: @PrimusSingularis а можно подробнее про связку с Dapper. Ссылку на гайд какой-нибудь подробный.. =/

Comment: @Mr.Modest http://blog.maskalik.com/asp-net/sqlite-simple-database-with-dapper/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Можно использовать `Access` в качестве локальной БД, если не планируется хранить огроменное кол-во данных.(Access поддерживает бд не более 2гб).

Наличие самого `Office` не требуется, можно поставить бесплатный `Access Engine` для работы с `Access`.

Касательно `LINQ`, то вы можете работать с таблицами в памяти через `LINQ` запросы к `DataTable`, а потом при завершении работы, переносить данные в `Access`.

Так же вместо работы через `DataTable` можно описать сущности в виде классов и с использованием `Dapper` написать свою ORM.
Dapper имеет автомапинг, что позволяет отражать возвращаемые запросов данные автоматически на поля класса.

Если изобретать велосипед не хочется, то можно поискать готовую ORM. Если не ошибаюсь, то `NHibernate` поддерживает работу с `Access` [из коробки](https://developer.jboss.org/wiki/DatabasesSupportedByNHibernate).

Comment: ну... количество строк на таблицу может достигать где-то 5-6 тысяч по идее...

Comment: 5-6 тысяч строк- это копейки. Если конечно ты не собираешься сами файлы в БД хранить.

Comment: нет. ни сама программа, ни БД не будет работать с файлами.. максимум это 4-5 таблиц с 30 полями в каждой.. строки и числа

Comment: Ну тогда Access тебе вполне хватит. Есть еще Microsoft SQL Server Compact Edition, но с ним я не работа=> возможно он не так прост в развертвывании на машине клиента.

Comment: тогда ещё такой вопрос. При условии, что я, например, поля классов этих самых сериалов и поля в таблице назову одинаково, есть ли удобные автозаполнители БД для чего-то вроде List<Title> titles или всё же лучше вручную самому заполнять БД?

Comment: Есть Dapper. Если ты опишешь класс, так же как таблица в бд, то при вызове conn.Query<Table1>("SELECT * FROM Table1").ToList() автоматически вернет тебе заполненный список и сам все замапит тебе.

Comment: Спасибо. Буду пробовать)

Comment: @iluxa1810, Microsoft SQL Server Compact Edition очень просто разворачивается, использовал в одном из проектов. Просто пара библиотек и БД в одном файле. Можно таскать хоть на флешке. Добавил ответ.

Answer (score 3):

Используйте обычную сериализацию, в любой нравящийся вам формат(XML, MS-NRBF, JSON, Protocol Buffers, или вообще в "собственноручно написанный на коленке за 5 минут") - из коробки это выполнит все вышепоставленные вами условия, в том числе и про LINQ.

Я вполне серьезно. Не вижу особого смысла на данном этапе проекта, и с этими условиями использовать полноценную базу данных - минусов будет больше чем плюсов.

Comment: количество строк кода может достигать 5000, а количество полей в таблицах 30.. меня пугает само существование текстового файла подобных размеров.. к тому же, фанатичная оптимизация не входит в планы.. а вот дальнейшая поддержка проекта с приоритете.

Comment: @Mr.Modest при грамотной работе с файловыми потоками, и 100к записей не вызовет, заметного на глаз, проседания производительности.

Comment: @rdorn и всё же, опыт работы с БД для меня был бы полезнее)

Comment: зачем велосипедить, писать серилизаторы, и их потом поддерживать?  Работать с локальной базой в разы проще.

Comment: @PrimusSingularis, вы же имели ввиду форматтеры? Можно просто использовать готовые, благо под .Net их реализовано не одна сотня. Никто не требует "изобретения велосипедов".

Answer (score 3):

Рассмотрите вариант использования MS SQL Server Compact, это, по сути, однопользовательская embedded версия SQL Server, есть полная поддержка Entity Framework.

Несколько лет не обновлялась, но вполне себе полноценный рабочий продукт.

Подключаете к своему приложению пару библиотек и можно хоть с флешки запускать.

Ссылки по теме:

[Microsoft SQL Server Compact Edition (Wikipedia)](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_SQL_Server_Compact_Edition)

[Download Microsoft SQL Server Compact 4.0 (official)](https://www.microsoft.com/ru-RU/download/details.aspx?id=17876)

[Microsoft SQL Server Compact Edition (nuget)](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SqlServerCompact/)

[EntityFramework.SqlServerCompact (nuget)](https://www.nuget.org/packages/EntityFramework.SqlServerCompact/)

[CompactView download (простая но мощная смотрелка БД MS SQL Server CE)](https://sourceforge.net/projects/compactview/)

Comment: >>Microsoft SQL Server Compact Edition (nuget)  -  то есть можно прямо из студии подключить всё необходимое из nuget? а как в таком варианте создавать новую БД и таблицы? из самой студии?

Comment: Можно с помощью Entity Framework. Можно с помощью sql запросов в CompactView, можно в студии через Server Explorer (или как он там называется)