# Оффлайн база данных для игры

Tags: c#, sql, база-данных, postgresql, разработка-игр

Здравствуйте, мне немного непонятно по поводу оффлайн баз данных. Я хочу иметь БД, которая не будет иметь никакого отношения к серверу и будет находится в самой игре. Разъясните, пожалуйста, мне этот вопрос. Параллельно пишу БД для сервера на postgresql, может можно организовать такое на нем. Спасибо!

Comment: Что Вам разъяснить??Нам вообще не понятно по какому поводу создан этот вопрос...

Comment: Вам нужна встроенная бд, смотрите SQLite, MS SQL CE, Firebird embedded, и т.д. Сервер управления БД в этом случае представляет собой библиотеку, которая подключается к приложению, бд переносная в файлике, таскаете за приложением.

Comment: Еще есть отсоединенный DataSet, реализованный исключительно средствами С# и хранящий систему таблиц в виде ХML-файла, но это годится только если данных мало. Выше Вам очень хорошо подсказали - правильнее использовать одну из перечисленных выше локальных баз данных.

Comment: @Андрей оформите ответ, ну что вы как не родной?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

То что вам нужно - называется встроенная/локальная/embedded БД.
Тут выбор очень велик и зависит от ваших потребностей. Если вы предпочитаете использовать `Entity Framework` - я рекомендую `MS SQL Server Compact`, здесь наилучшая поддержка - достаточно подключить один NuGet-пакет.
Чуть больше информации в этом ответе: [ссылка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/617995/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%8E-%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%8E-%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%83-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%B2-visual-st/618025#618025)

Также вполне себе работает с `EF` embedded-версия `Firebird`: [ссылка](https://www.firebirdsql.org/en/firebird-2-5-7/), но придется подшаманить, гугл поможет.

Если БД вам нужна преимущественно для чтения из нее (ну там ресурсы игры хранить, например), то можно использовать "Micro ORM" `Dapper` - это по сути маппер-надстройка над `ADO.NET` и тут у вас выбор гораздо больше, можете использовать помимо указанных выше, `SQLite`, `MySQL` (это из наиболее популярных) ... да хоть `MS Access`. Этот вариант в несколько раз производительнее чем `EF`, но в то же время берет на себя всю работу по маппингу строк БД на ваш сущностный класс.