# Файловая БД для C#

Tags: c#, база-данных

Начал изучать C# и возник вопрос, есть ли какая нативная файловая БД для C# под Win, конечно есть SQLite, но думал что есть какое-то встроенное решение, нашёл что есть Microsoft SQL Server Compact , но он как я понял уже не поддерживается толком.

Comment: Как вариант [Embedded NoSQL database for .NET](http://www.litedb.org/)

Comment: Хорошая вещь эта LiteDB, может на ней и остановлюсь.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL Server Compact вполне себе неплохая БД. Дружит с EF. Использовал в нескольких проектах. Из минусов это скорость работы (Достаточно медленная) и невозможность переименовывания колонок.
К примеру вы переименуете класс и используя EF сделаете миграцию, только вот код миграции будет содержать команды переименовывания, которые не поддерживаются в SQL Server Compact.

А вот как хорошо будет работать EF с SQLite не могу ответить так как на практике не побывал.

Comment: SQLite, вроде еще год назад не поддерживал Code First. А насчет компакта - согласен, всё работает отлично

Comment: Здесь в ответе есть полезные ссылки: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/618025/218063

Comment: Единственное что пугает это то что с 13 года её прекратили разрабатывать ,и 2021 вообще снимут с поддержки, вот и думал может MS заменила эту БД чем-то более новым.

Comment: @vnn198: Не стоит этого боятся. Продукт хороший. Суть в том что необходимо выбирать для каких целей это вам нужно. Если хранить локальные данные пользователя в десктоп приложении, то вполне себе пойдет и еще довольно долго будет актуально. Если обрабатывать какие то огромные данные, то тогда не стоит даже рассматривать эти маллюсенькие БД)

Comment: @АндрейNOP это EF не поддерживать мог CodeFirst, а вот NHibernate давно умеет с SQLite в CodeFirst.

Comment: @Monk, а, ну да. Я просто в контексте этого ответа комментарий написал, поэтому так вышло не совсем удачно :)

Comment: Да БД нужна для хранения данных SMART, хочу написать сервис который будет каждый час снимать данные SMART и сохранять их