# C# и работа с локальным файлом MSSQL без сервера

Tags: c#, база-данных, sql-server, сервер

Всем привет.

Итак, у меня есть приложение C # .net3.5 x86 и база данных MS SQL.

И я должен позволить установить и использовать это приложение без дополнительной установки Denver, SQL Server или чего-либо еще.

Значит, я должен преобразовать свою БД в локальный файл .mdf и подключиться к нему.

Вопрос: как я могу это сделать? Нет, я-то могу, но у меня и студия, и SQL Server и всё такое. А обычный юзер с хрюшкой? То есть все приложение должно работать так, как будто оно работает с базой данных Access (то есть не зная самого слова "сервер" - всё должно быть локально, пользователи не должны париться о серверах или чём-то ещё), но это должен быть MS SQL.

Если можете, добавьте несколько примеров кода или ссылок. Слышал про SQL Lite, но как это присобачить...

Благодарю.

Comment: Гуглите с указанием ключевого слова `embedded`: `MySql embedded`. Но лично я бы с .NET использовал MS SQL Server CE

Comment: Коннектор это АПИ по доступу к серверу :) сервер mysql все равно будет нужен. Возможные пути решения: взять EF6 и через его систему доступа к контексту организовать два вида подключения, к дистанционному mysql и к локальной db от Microsoft. В сетапе соответственно можно выбирать с чем работать. Данному заказчику поставлять с предустановленной галочкой local db

Comment: @AleksKeller В таком случае я советую использовать СУБД SQLite  а не MySQL

Comment: Ээээ, уже .net 3.5? На XP 4.0 работает же. Вот топик со ссылками на нугет и прочее: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/618025/218063

Comment: @АндрейNOP уже не важно. По крайней мере, в данном случае - БД мне "милостиво разрешили" взять MSSQL. Вопрос, соответственно, изменился, так как отпала необходимость в коннекторах и прочей дичи

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если кто-то столкнётся с подобной проблемой - по совету Андрея NOP заюзал MS SQL Server CE. Редактор БД ставится в студию как обычное расширение, на ютубе есть мануалы по установке. 
Программа запускается даже на холодильнике)